# How to create dichotomous variables based on some factors in r?

Tags: r

The initial dataframe is:

```
Factor1   Factor2   Factor3
  A           B        C
  B           C        NA
  A           NA       NA
  B            C        D
  E           NA       NA
```

I want to create 5 dichotomous variables based on the above factor variables. The rule should be the new variable `A` will get 1 if either `Factor1` or `Factor2` or `Factor3` contains an `A` otherwise `A` should be 0, and so on. The newly created variables should look like:

```
A    B    C    D    E
1    1    1    0    0
0    1    1    0    0
1    0    0    0    0
0    1    1    1    0
0    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `table` to do this.  We replicate the sequence of rows with the number of columns, `unlist` the dataset and get the frequency of values.

```
table(rep(1:nrow(df1), ncol(df1)), unlist(df1))
#    A B C D E
#  1 1 1 1 0 0
#  2 0 1 1 0 0
#  3 1 0 0 0 0
#  4 0 1 1 1 0
#  5 0 0 0 0 1
```

If we have more than 1 value per row, then convert to logical and then reconvert it back to binary.

```
 +(!!table(rep(1:nrow(df1), ncol(df1)), unlist(df1)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Factor1 = c("A", "B", "A", "B", "E"),
 Factor2 = c("B", 
"C", NA, "C", NA), Factor3 = c("C", NA, NA, "D", NA)), 
 .Names = c("Factor1", 
 "Factor2", "Factor3"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: Thanks akrun. The answer looks fine. But, when I save the result as df2 it becomes an object of class table and when I convert it into a data frame by as.data.frame(df2) the format of the result is changed. How to store the result as a data frame (say, df2) so that A B C D E become the variable names of the df2?

Comment: @AmirulIslam  You can do `as.data.frame(as.matrix(table(` or make it compact as `as.data.frame.matrix(table(rep(1:nrow(df1), ncol(df1)), unlist(df1)))`

Comment: @ akrun, as.data.frame.matrix(table(rep(1:nrow(df1), ncol(df1)), unlist(df1))) is working fine.